# How to obtain derivative from a polynomial equation?

Tags: python, derivative

I was doing my own method to solve the derivative of the polynomial problem just for fun. But I come up with a problem. I could not delete or remove `'*x**2'` from `array_1 = '3*x**3 + 2*x**2 + 3*x + 5'` to obtain an array like this; `array = [3, 2, 3, 5]`.

```
array_1 = '3*x**3 + 2*x**2 + 3*x + 5'

def converter(array_1):
    array_1 = array_1.split(' + ')

    return str(array_1)

array = [5, 3, 2] # for testing ( I reversed order of an array.)

def derivative(array):
    new_array = []
    for x, elem in enumerate(array):
        z = x*elem
        new_array.append(z)
    return new_array[1:]



result = derivative(array)
print(result)
print(converter(array_1))
```

Comment: how about using regular expressions so that take a character that is before + or - signs?

Comment: It makes sense but I should not lose coefficients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `array` is just a string—which is nothing but a sequence of characters. So each `elem` is just going to be a single character. What you need to do is write a *parser*.

---

For something this simple, you could parse everything with just string operations, or [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) if you know how to use them or want to read a tutorial on them. Here's an example with just the methods of the `str` class:

```
s = '3*x**3 + 2*x**2 + 3*x + 5'
for term in s.split('+'):
    coefficient, _, factor = term.partition('*')
    variable, power = factor.partition('**')
    do_something_with(coefficient, variable, power)
```

(Of course you probably want to turn the `coefficient` and `power` into numbers in that `do_something_with` code, but that's easy; just use `int` or `float`.)

But this will be somewhat brittle. It'll handle the exact format you have (as long as `do_something_with` can deal with extra whitespace, and with empty strings for `variable` and `power`—just calling `int` or `float` can handle the former, but not the latter). But if you try it with, say, `3 * x**3 + 2 * x**2 + 3 * x + 5`, it will fail.

---

A better option is to use a parsing or parser-generating library. There's a bit of a learning curve, but it's worth doing. For example, [`pyparsing`](http://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/) is a reasonably easy one to learn, there are some great tutorials out there for it, and it comes with extensive [examples](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples), one of which I think is pretty close to what you're doing.

---

Finally, your format happens to be a subset of Python syntax. You could take advantage of that by using [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), the Python parser that comes with Python. However, this isn't exactly a novice-friendly option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. I know it is not functional. I'll try to improve it.

```
array_1 = '3*x**3 + 2*x**2 + 3*x + 5'

def converter(array_1):
    array_1 = array_1.split(' + ')
    print(array_1)

    new_array = []
    for x in array_1:
        new_array.append(x[-0])

    return new_array

array = [5, 3, 2] # for testing

def derivative(array):
    new_array = []
    for x, elem in enumerate(array):
        z = x*elem
        new_array.append(z)
    return new_array[1:]



result = derivative(array)
print(result)
print(converter(array_1))
```

Output:

```
[3, 4]
['3*x**3', '2*x**2', '3*x', '5']
['3', '2', '3', '5']
```